# How can I submit a form doing POST of data on IONIC?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to do a POST on ionic submitting a form with an array of data but I don't know how I can do this (but if I do this in POSTMAN, it actually works).

[image: PETITION POST]

I tried with this form but didn't work:

```
  submitRegistration(value):void{

var headers = new Headers();
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');

let link = 'http://apidata.com/';

let myData = {
  fos_user_registration_form: [{
    _token: this.data.token,
    username: value.usuario,
    email: value.correo,
    plainPassword: [{
      first: value.password,
      second: value.confirmPassword
    }],
    userLocalization: value.municipio}
  ]};

console.log(myData);

this.http.post(link, myData, options)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.data.response = data["_body"];
  }, error => {
    alert("Oooops!");
  });
```

}

Can anyone help me?

Comment: try ...this.http.post(link, JSON.stringify(myData), options).. and see if that works

Comment: Check in console for errors, and also look at the Network-tab at the specific request for any clues on what's going on. It's hard to solve this without any debug information.

Comment: i can't do debug.. I only can try this on mobile because the server has the CORS

Comment: without debug information its hard to suggest some solution

Comment: I think i'll use something like axios

Answer (score 0):

You have to stringify the data before you post,try this

```
this.http.post(link, JSON.stringify(myData), options)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.data.response = data["_body"];
  }, error => {
    alert("Oooops!");
  });
```

It should do the trick

Comment: There is no need to stringify it actually :)

Comment: isn't that a plane array without a key value pair in the required json format?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i find the solution (for me). Here the code

```
  submitRegistration(value):void{

var headers = new Headers();
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

let link = 'http://APIREST.com/';

let myData = 'fos_user_registration_form[_token]='+encodeURI(this.data.token);
myData += '&fos_user_registration_form[username]='+encodeURI(value.usuario);
myData += '&fos_user_registration_form[email]='+encodeURI(value.correo);
myData += '&fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][first]='+encodeURI(value.password);
myData += '&fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][second]='+encodeURI(value.confirmPassword);
myData += '&fos_user_registration_form[userLocalization]='+encodeURI(value.municipio);

console.log(myData);

this.http.post(link, myData, options)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.data.response = data["_body"];
    console.log(data);
  }, error => {
    console.log("Oooops!");
  });
```

}

Comment: If you append form parameters to your API url, then use `URLSearchParams`, because it realize that you need. Maybe `FormData` is interesting for you.